# Accessing MySQL Stored Procedures in Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have been working on a Ruby web app using MySQL for the database. I heard from a friend that the `mysql` gem did not work well with stored procedures, so I decided to use the `mysql2` gem along with the `seqel` gem.

I have a stored procedure in MySQL called `AddUser(Username, Password)`. It works fine from MySQL. I want to access it using the gems for security reasons.

The `sqeuel` doc [here](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/prepared_statements_rdoc.html) only really covers how to access databases made with the `sequel` gem. My first-draft code looked something like this, but doesn't actually run the procedure

```
# Connect to the database
db = Sequel.mysql2(
    :host => '127.0.0.1', 
    :database => database, 
    :username => username, 
    :password => password)

# Call the sproc
db["User"]
db.call_sproc(:insert, "AddUser", [name, pass])
```

The error message is:

`Sequel::DatabaseError`

`Mysql2::Error: Query was empty`

Comment: should it be `prepare_sproc` and `call_sproc`?

Comment: Thanks, that seems like it's more correct. I'm still having trouble, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure whether a PreparedStatement is actually capable of calling a stored procedure.  Certainly in JDBC you'd have to use a CallableStatement to do this.

Since you're using Sequel, have you had a look at Sequel::DataSet::StoredProcedures (http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc-adapters/classes/Sequel/Dataset/StoredProcedures.html) ?

Comment: Thanks, that definitely seems to be a better place to look. I'm still having problems, though, would you mind looking at my edit?

Comment: This thread [http://osdir.com/ml/sequel-talk/2010-06/msg00001.html] may be of use.  I've only noodled around with Sequel as a possible replacement for ActiveRecord 3, not for doing any SP work in Ruby.  You may need to build up stored proc calls manually and execute them manually.